# Joining of pages from same PDF Form results in un-saveable PDF in itextSharp

Tags: c#, forms, merge, itext

I have an application PDF form consisting of 2 pages. The second page should be used only if the first page does not have enough space. And if the second page does not, one should print then a new copy of page 2.
Therefore, my object is to build a method to create a form having page 1 + variable number of pages 2.
As if I simply concatenate the pdfs using PDFcopyfields would duplicate fields, I used the method from Lowagie's to renumber the duplicated fields.
So far, I have only been able to duplicate the whole document 'n' times (ie., a document having the same number of pages 1 + pages 2) using the pdfcopyfields. Moreover, the worst is that the document cannot be saved.

```
public void Write()
{
    PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(new FileStream(@"C:\users\u19\desktop\33.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(RenameFieldsIn(@"C:\users\u19\desktop\1.pdf", 1)));
    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(RenameFieldsIn(@"C:\users\u19\desktop\1.pdf", 2)));
    // close the PdfCopyFields object
    copy.Close();

}

private static byte[] RenameFieldsIn(string datasheet, int i)
{
    List<string> form_keys = new List<string>();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Create the stamper
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(datasheet), ms))
        {
            // Get the fields
            AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
            // so we aren't hit with 'Collection was modified' exception
            foreach (string k in stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Keys)
            {
                form_keys.Add(k);
            }
            // Loop over the fields
            foreach (string key in form_keys)
            {
                // rename the fields
                form.RenameField(key, string.Format("{0}_{1}", key, i));
            }
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have a 'Reader-enabled' form, you have a PDF that is digitally signed using a private key owned by Adobe that unlocks functionality in Adobe Reader, for instance: the permission to save a document. Merging such a form inevitably breaks the digital signature and removes that permission. You can only reinstate that permission with Adobe software. In other words: you're trying to achieve something that is impossible without Adobe software (in this context: impossible means illegal because you'd need to "steal" Adobe's private key to achieve what you want).

Comment: Actually, I could not found any signature in the form: (for your reference: http://ion.inapi.cl:8080/FormulariosPdf/patente/40.solicitud%20Registro%20de%20Patente.pdf). However, the doc may be signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already explained in a comment, your PDF is "Reader-enabled". Reader-enabling involves a digital signature using Adobe's private key. You claim that the PDF you're trying to fill out doesn't contain any signature. However, you shared a PDF and when I look at this document, I clearly see a **Usage Rights** (UR) signature:

[image]

This signature (if valid) unlocks functionality in Adobe Reader, for instance: the permission to save a document. Merging such a form inevitably breaks the digital signature and removes that permission. You can only reinstate that permission with Adobe software.
If you look closely, you can see that your PDF was reader-enabled using Acrobat v8.0.

In other words: you're trying to achieve something that is impossible without Adobe as you need to digitally sign the document using a private key that is the property of Adobe.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks for the explanation!